# Why my thread is resumed after a WaitMessage if the event was WM_MOVE?

Tags: windows, wine

In Windows it happens that a thread sleeping on the `WaitMessage` function is *resumed* if there is a `WM_MOVE` or `WM_ACTIVATE` message, even though these messages are not queued (i.e., I will not get them with `PeekMessage`.)

The question is whether this behavior is consistent with the documentation because when running in Wine the behavior I observe is different, the thread is activated but not resumed were it got slept and instead the `WinProc` is directly invoked.

**EDIT:**
Let me rephrase so the question becomes clearer:

1. My thread sends `WaitMessage`
2. The user *touches* the app window, so the action ends up triggering `VM_MOVE`

I see two possibilities:

1. The thread is resumed right after `WaitMessage`
2. The thread is activated with `WndProc`, i.e., not right after `WaitMessage`

Does any of these describe the actual behavior? Also, in case 1 should I get anything if I immediately call `PeekMessage`?

Given that `WM_MOVE` is not a queued message and `WaitMessage` waits for a message to be queued, should the thread be awoken? If yes, should it resume right after `WaitMessage` or should the `WndProc` be invoked directly?

The reason I'm asking is because I seem to be getting two different behaviors in Windows and Wine. In Windows the thread resumes right after `WaitMessage`, in Wine the thread is activated in `WndProc`.

Comment: So when you call `PeekMessage` after `WaitMessage` returns, `PeekMessage` does not yield a queued message?

Comment: Post your code.   That's not supposed to happen and probably isn't.

Comment: Would you really deem the thread "teleporting" out of the current stack frame into `WndProc` a valid thing to happen?

Comment: @Damon. No, I certainly don't deem that valid and I haven't seen this happening in Windows. However, I've been able to reproduce this in Wine and that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: @BadZen I agree in that this doesn't happen in Windows. However, it happens in Wine when I maximize the window. I've inspected the stack and I see that WnProc was called directly (i.e., without resuming after `WaitMessage`)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, that's hard to check and that's why I posted the question, to have a better understanding of the expected behavior. The reason that Wine seems to react differently (very often when I maximize the window) made me think that I was missing something.

Comment: ahhhh.   Wine is a big ball of duct-tapey-kludge.   Best to check with its source or developers I think, given this new info.  Will try to reproduce/analyze if you post source, tho...